# crosstool-ng gccgo build error with undefined morestack symbols

Tags: go, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng, gccgo

I'm building gccgo with crosstool-ng 1.24.0. Got linker error when compiling the very simple main.go. Any idea how to solve this? Any pointer to a successful gogcc build even for a different popular target that can easily be verified?

The host is ubuntu 18.04 with gcc 7.3.0. The crosstool-ng target is x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu which should create gcc 8.3.0 with glibc 2.23.

Here are the missing symbols:

```
undefined reference to `__morestack_block_signals'
undefined reference to `__generic_morestack'
undefined reference to `__morestack_unblock_signals'
undefined reference to `__morestack_block_signals'
undefined reference to `__generic_releasestack'
undefined reference to `__generic_findstack'
undefined reference to `__generic_morestack_set_initial_sp'
undefined reference to `__morestack_load_mmap'
```

---

More details of the build steps:

[1] Check out crosstool-ng. It's master is now on 1.24.0.

[2] Run these commands to build a plain c and c++ toolchain:

```
./bootstrap
./configure --enable-local
make
./ct-ng show-x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu
./ct-ng x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu
./ct-ng build
```

[3] Verify that the gcc works by compiling a hello-world program and run.

[4] Edit the script to enable go. The patch looks like:

```
diff --git a/scripts/build/cc/gcc.sh b/scripts/build/cc/gcc.sh
@@ -597,7 +597,7 @@ do_gcc_core_backend() {
-        --enable-languages="${lang_list}"              \
+        --enable-languages="${lang_list},go"              \
@@ -903,7 +903,7 @@ do_gcc_backend() {
-    extra_config+=("--enable-languages=${lang_list}")
+    extra_config+=("--enable-languages=${lang_list},go")
```

[5] Run `./ct-ng build` again.

[6] Compile a very simple main.go:

```
// main.go
package main

import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Ok, ok, this is exactly perfect!\n")
}
```

Using command:

```
PATH=${HOME}/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/:${PATH}
export PATH

x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu-gccgo -o main main.go
```

Got these errors:

```
~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/8.3.0/libgcc.a(morestack.o): 
in function `__morestack':

~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:504:
undefined reference to `__morestack_block_signals'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:512:
undefined reference to `__generic_morestack'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:531:
undefined reference to `__morestack_unblock_signals'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:556:
undefined reference to `__morestack_block_signals'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:562:
undefined reference to `__generic_releasestack'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:588:
undefined reference to `__morestack_unblock_signals'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:609:
undefined reference to `__generic_findstack'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/8.3.0/libgcc.a(morestack.o):
in function `__stack_split_initialize':

~/crosstool-ng/.build/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/config/i386/morestack.S:758:
undefined reference to `__generic_morestack_set_initial_sp'

~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
~/x-tools/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/x86_64-ubuntu16.04-linux-gnu/8.3.0/libgcc.a(morestack.o):
(.ctors.65535+0x8):
undefined reference to `__morestack_load_mmap'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Also built the same inside a xenial docker container with host gcc 5.4. Same problem.